# How to get a side-by-side view with difftool

Tags: git

I want to view changes to all files in a **single** view as pictured; preferably selecting two revisions and launching diff from GUI.

[image]

The closest I can get is to launch

```
git difftool -t meld -d 2e9c5b 4fce22
```

and click each file to view it's diff. I know meld has this capability. What is a way to launch a diff of all files, from gitk/git gui if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'd only ever need side by side viewing for those commits that if merged would cause a merge conflict, you could always use mergetool, with your merge tool set to vimdiff.

With this in mind, you could do a really hacky script which creates merge conflicts from patches for changes that don't cause conflicts on a staging branch, and then attempt to do a branch merge of that temp branch into your current head. . .

Answer (score 0):

OSX-specific, but this is actually pretty easy with Tower. You can configure your diff tool, which could be FileMerge, which comes with XCode, or [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/)

[image]

For Windows (Mac as well), check out [SourceTree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/), which like Tower, uses the difftool you've specified in your global .gitconfig file.